# Asymptotic behaviour of absolute different of two independent Poisson processes

Tags: stochastic-processes

Suppose we have $X_1,X_2\sim Po(\lambda)$ ($X_1$ and $X_2$ are independent). Consider the interval $[0,1]$ with 100000 subintervals of length $\Delta=\frac{1}{100000}$.
I can calculate:

$$E|X_1-X_2|=2e^{-2\lambda}\sum_{i,k=1}^{\infty}k\frac{\lambda^{2i+k}}{(i+k)!i!}$$

Therefore, $E|\Delta X_1-\Delta X_2|=2e^{-2\lambda\Delta}\sum_{i,k=1}^{\infty}k\frac{(\lambda\Delta)^{2i+k}}{(i+k)!i!}$. If now I walk along vector$X=X_1-X_2$ with step 
of size $m$, we then have: $E|\Delta X_1-\Delta X_2|=2e^{-2\lambda m\Delta}\sum_{i,k=1}^{\infty}k\frac{(\lambda m\Delta)^{2i+k}}{(i+k)!i!}$.  I ran some simulation and find out that the probability $|\Delta X_1-\Delta X_2|$ have more than 2 
jumps is very small. Thus,$E|\Delta X_1-\Delta X_2|=2e^{-2\lambda m\Delta}[\lambda m\Delta+(\lambda m\Delta)^2+\frac{1}{2}(\lambda m\Delta)^3]$. I would like to examine 
the asymptotic behaviour of $\sum_1^n|\Delta X_1-\Delta X_2|$. We have:
$$\frac{1}{n}\sum_1^n|\Delta X_1-\Delta X_2|\to E|\Delta X_1-\Delta X_2|$$
or
$$\frac{1}{n}\sum_1^n|\Delta X_1-\Delta X_2|\sim 2e^{-2\lambda m\Delta}[\lambda m\Delta+(\lambda m\Delta)^2+\frac{1}{2}(\lambda m\Delta)^3]$$
Note that $n=\frac{1}{m\Delta}$, then
$$\sum_1^n|\Delta X_1-\Delta X_2|\sim \frac{1}{m\Delta}\times 2e^{-2\lambda m\Delta}[\lambda m\Delta+(\lambda m\Delta)^2+\frac{1}{2}(\lambda m\Delta)^3]$$
I got stuck at this step since I cant say anything about asymptotic behaviour of the LHS using the RHS when $m$ getting smaller. Does it behave as order 1 of $m$? 
Can some one please tell me if I am on the right track or I made a mistake somewhere?

Comment: What are $\Delta X_1$ and $\Delta X_2$?

Comment: Sorry for not making it clear, $\Delta X_1 = X_1(t_i)-X_1(t_{i-1})$ and $\Delta X_2 = X_2(t_i)-X_2(t_{i-1})$. Thanks @Did

Comment: Are you computing the average value of $X_1-X_2$ or the average value of $|X_1-X_2|$?

Comment: hi @JackD'Aurizio, I am aiming for the total variation of $X_1-X_2$ which is $\sum_1^n |\Delta X_1- \Delta X_2|$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For any $m\in\mathbb{N}$, we have:
$$\mathbb{P}[X_1-X_2=m]=\sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}\mathbb{P}[X_1=m+n]\mathbb{P}[X_2=n]=\lambda^m e^{-2\lambda}\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}\frac{\lambda^{2n}}{(m+n)!n!}$$
or:
$$\mathbb{P}[X_1-X_2=m]=e^{-2\lambda}I_m(2\lambda)$$
where $I_m$ is a [hyperbolic Bessel function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_function).

By symmetry, the probability mass function of $X_1-X_2$ is given by:
$$\mathbb{P}[X_1-X_2=m]=e^{-2\lambda}I_{|m|}(2\lambda)$$
for any $m\in\mathbb{Z}$, and:
$$\mathbb{E}[|X_1-X_2|]=e^{-2\lambda}\sum_{m=1}^{+\infty}2m\, I_m(2\lambda)=\frac{e^{-2\lambda}}{\pi}\int_{0}^{\pi}\exp(2\lambda\cos\theta)\sum_{m=1}^{+\infty}2m\cos(m\theta)\,d\theta.$$
Since:
$$ I_m(2\lambda)\leq\frac{\lambda^m}{m!}I_0(2\lambda) $$
we have the upper bound:

$$\mathbb{E}[|X_1-X_2|]\leq e^{-2\lambda}I_0(2\lambda)\sum_{m=1}^{+\infty}\frac{2m\lambda^m}{m!}=\color{red}{2\lambda e^{-\lambda}I_0(2\lambda)}\approx\color{blue}{e^\lambda\sqrt{\frac{\lambda}{\pi}}}.$$

Comment: thanks so much, @Jack D'Aurizio. Your solution using Bessel function is brilliant, I learnt new thing today!